# Subordinating Clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses

Given:

> Building these houses entails a lot of work.

Does 'these houses entails a lot of work' form a subordinating clause to the verb 'building'? If so what kind of subordinating clause is it?

Comment: I would divide it differently. "Building these houses" is the subject, "entails a lot of work" is what that activity does. I think it's the main clause, not a subordinate.

Comment: No: "Building these houses" is the subordinate clause; it functions as subject. "These houses" is a noun phrase functioning as object of "building". "Entails a lot of work" is a verb phrase function as predicate.

Comment: @BILLJ,   In that case would a phrase tree  look like?   is the entire sentence a verse phrase, with no subclauses and only  a noun phrase?

Comment: No: the sentence is a main clause containing the subordinate clause "building these houses" as subject, and the verb phrase "entails a lot of work" as predicate.